# SDL - C++ can't load more than one image

Tags: c++, sdl

I can't load more than a png: indeed the only image to be blittered is the first to load. There's no error.

```
boy = IMG_Load(strcat(imagedir,"boy.png"));
SDL_Rect boyrect = {0,0,50,50};
SDL_BlitSurface( boy, &boyrect, screen, NULL );
bar = IMG_Load(strcat(imagedir,"bar.png"));
SDL_Rect barrect = {0,-SCREEN_HEIGHT+150,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT};
SDL_BlitSurface( bar, &barrect, screen, NULL );
```

Comment: Unless there's code you're not showing us, the second call tries to load `.../boy.pngbar.png`. And why are you using `strcat` in C++ in the first place?

Comment: ah,sorry. I thought that strcat create a new string. Thank you. I wanted  to use strcat in order to change the image directory just changing the imagedir variable

Comment: @user595897: use std::string, then you can do something like path = imagedir + imagename; boy = IMG_Load(path.c_str()); where path, imagedir and imagename are all std::strings. You can even leave off the imagename and just do path = imagedir + "boy.png";

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is the SDL_Rect from source, and the fourth argument the zone to paste.

I think you want to paste each png in a part of the screen.

```
SDL_BlitSurface( boy, NULL, screen, &boyrect );
SDL_BlitSurface( bar, NULL, screen, &barrect );
```